# xscreensaver running on lightdm GTK greeter

Tags: lightdm, xscreensaver

This is a dorky question and the merits of it are pointless. I have a system for guests and I want a BSOD screensaver for the login. I've been fiddling around for a while with various attempts at making it happen.

The system runs Debian Jessie.

What I tried at least got the xscreensaver-demo window running when lightdm starts. The daemon will not start. If someone can help me get the daemon to start it will be a step in the right direction. In fact, all my problems should be solved.

At this point I've not cared about security implications. I found I can have a script for the greeter by adding this line to /etc/lightdm.conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/xscreensaver-script.sh
```

The script simply was this, so I could get xscreensaver-demo to run and bootstrap what I want. It says this greeter setup script runs as root, and just having the script run xscreensaver-demo did create a window. However, it could not start the xscreensaver daemon.

I then tried running xscreensaver-demo as lightdm with this with my script:

```
su -l "lightdm" -c "/usr/bin/xscreensaver-demo" &
```

At that point nothing happened, and I am running out of ideas and bad hacks to attempt this. I honestly don't understand lightdm very well, but I still think this can be done.

Note: I am trying to get xscreensaver-demo running so I can select a screensaver, after that the greeter can just run with xscreensaver.

I've considered adding a window manager to the greeter, but twm is all that came to mind and manually placing all the windows lightdm makes it pretty silly.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here, and it is easy to install:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
sudo apt-get xscreensaver-extra-data
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod
```

The beauty of it is that you get to select (in Settings) which style  you like, and you can even have it cycle through them.  I like the sad Mac to show up now and then.  But linux-looking gibberish works great also.

People actually wonder if there is a problem and are afraid to touch it.  Perfect for a screen saver.

(Of course, LCD and LED screens don't need saving like CRT's did but that's beside the point)

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

You are probably forgetting to give xscreensaver the proper authentication cookies.

See https://github.com/the-cavalry/light-locker/issues/81 for an example on how to do this, and since you're not using light-locker the issue doesn't apply, and the scripts mentioned in that post should "just work" for you.